# why does resizing image in Pillow-python remove Image.format?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm resizing images in python using Pillow

```
image = Image.open("image_file.jpg")

print(image.format) # Prints JPEG

resized_image = image.resize([100,200],PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

print(resized_image.format) # Prints None!!
```

Why does `resized_image.format` Hold a `None` Value?

And How can i retain the format when resizing using pillow?

Comment: If you're concerned that you won't be able to save your new image as a jpg, go ahead and try it - I'm pretty sure `resized_image.save("output.jpg")` will work even when `resized_image.format` isn't "JPEG".

Comment: @Kevin Yes it did :) Although I  think the format attribute should be passed on resizing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because [Image.resize](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) creates a new [Image](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image) object (resized copy of the image) and for any images when creating by the library itself (via a factory function, or by running a method on an existing image), the "[format](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.format)" attribute is set to **None**.

If you need the format attribute you still can to do this:

```
image = Image.open("image_file.jpg") #old image object
resized_image = image.resize([100,200],PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
resized_image.format = image.format # original image extension
```

[Read the docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.format)

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html):

> The file format of the source file. For images created by the library itself (via a factory function, or by running a method on an existing image), this attribute is set to None.

You can specify the format on save:

```
image.save(fp, 'JPEG')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the resized images with save comments

```
resized_image.save("New_image.png")
```

It will save into your current directory.

If you want to see in the python console itself you have to run

```
resized_image.show()
```